# What's the equivalent of the set data function of a Flex 3 item renderer in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Please see question above. Thanks!

Comment: There is no change; so the equivalent of a set data function in a Flex 3 itemRenderer will translate to a set data function in a Flex 4 itemRenderer.  Perhaps you should explain the problem you're having, or read the documentation?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html

Comment: Why was it voted down???

Comment: I guess there was a downv ote because you didn't provide any content in the body of the question; other than to refer people to the subject line.  The subject line should not be your only content.  You didn't provide any elaboration or description or any proof you did minimal research on the topic.

Comment: But the question has already been answered. Why vote it down now?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted; so I Don't know.  But; I assume that someone thought this question and answer did nothing to make the Internet a better place; and in facts detracts from the purpose of the site.

Comment: Whom do I need to talk to in order to undo the down vote?

Comment: You need to talk to whomever downvoted you and convince them to undo it; presumably you'll do that after editing the question to make it more appropriate.  However I don't believe there is any way to find who downvoted you [other than reviewing everyone's profiles and looking at their rep score changes].  Don't let it worry you too much.  Downvotes happen for all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flex 4 the have introduced <s:ItemRenderer to avoid using <mx:Hbox etc., components which are very heavy indeed. So, all the hgroup etc spark components will not have set data property, you might have to skin the spark itemrenderer and use it as a renderer.

and as said in the comment to your question, there is no change in the set data property.